# How to output LaTeX/TeX Tikz packages inside Julia

Tags: julia, latex, tex, ijulia-notebook

I wanted to output Circuitikz inside my Julia Notebook, How do I install [circuitikz](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz) to my notebook, Or how do I run Circuitikz inside my Julia code

```
using Latexify
using LaTeXStrings

str = L"""
\begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}
      \tikz \draw (0,0) to[R=5<\sigma>] (2,0) to [V=5<\volt>] ( 3,0)
                    ;
    \end{circuitikz}
    \caption{My first circuit. Just for learning Circuitikz}
  \end{center}
"""

latexify(str)
```

## Output

```
"$\begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}
      \tikz \draw (0,0) to[R=5<\sigma>] (2,0) to [V=5<\volt>] ( 3,0)
                                        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
    \caption{My first circuit. Just for learning LaTeX}
  \end{center}
$"
```

Comment: No idea about Julia Notebooks, but in tex this would  error. The `\caption` macro needs to be used in a figure, table etc., not a `center` environment.

Comment: What's your question? Or what is the problem with the code you posted? What happens when you run it and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Comment: For the general question of "how to get rendered LaTeX in a Julia notebook", [LatexSVG.jl](https://github.com/EHBaozi/LatexSVG.jl) would be an answer. Unfortunately, the `dvisvgm` tool it relies on to create the SVG images seems to be unable to handle `circuitikz`-generated output. The resulting SVG from that is a garbled mess for those cases.